# Injecting a singleton into scopedService

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

I'm working on adding push notification into my ASP.NET core 2.0.0 webApp. I want to have a notification service that would have a `badgeCount` member which I would update when I send out notifications or when I mark something as read.

I wanted to make this a singleton, but it seems like I can't use dependency injection for singletons. I need access to my dbContext and maybe some other Identity /or Entity services later.

Would it make sense for me to make my notifcation service a scopedService instead of a singleton so that I can use DI? Then have a notificationBadge singleton that I would inject into my scopedService so I can maintain it?

I'm doing this so that I don't have to calculate the badge count each time (involves using queries)

EDIT: Actually, after writing this I realized that singletons are probably only instantiated once on server startup and not per user. So my initial approach wouldn't work even if I could use DI. I'd probably have to add a field on my user class that extends the IdentityUser then right? Or is there a way around this so that I don't have to update/save this to any db record?

Comment: `but it seems like I can't use dependency injection for singletons` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(new MyService(PassInStuff))` Doesn't adding a singleton require me to pass in all the required things up front like this instead of injecting it in the contructor?

Comment: "Actually, after writing this I realized that singletons are probably only instantiated once on server startup and not per use" this is exactly true. If you want per-request use `services.AddScoped` and if you want "a new one every time" use `services.AddTransient`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] showing how you are registering a singleton and a non-singleton.

Comment: If you want your badgeCount to be permanently mapped to a user, you need to store it in the database. However, you can request it only on user login and save it on user logout, by using a static ConcurrentDictionary with key of userID and value of badgeCount.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev Or use `Session`...

Comment: I don't think I need it to be saved because I can calculate it onUserLogin. Would session be around as long as my user is logged in? Would it make sense to store it though?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, this is even better unless he is writing a Web Api app.

Comment: @user6728767 That depends on how you implement it. AFAIK you may set up the cookies so that the login never expires but as far as I remember the session lasts 20 minutes or so by default. It's a matter of configuration though. It makes sense to store it if it's expensive to calculate and won't change too often

Comment: I am making a web api app. If the endpoint can be hit from my website and mobileApp would it matter at all if I'm using a session? It'd prob just recalculate if I put that function onLogin and both the website and mobile sessions would have the right count?

Comment: Also it is important whether you need only current logged user's badge or all logged users badges.

Comment: I think I would need it for all logged users. I just want to have the badge ready when I call my pushNotificationService to push a notification to my ios/android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Understanding DI

So to try and cover your question DI is certainly what you want in terms of most things inside your application and website. It can do singletons, as well as scoped and transcients (new copy every time).

In order to really understand DI and specifically the .Net Core implenentation I actually make use of the DI from .Net Core in a stand-alone .Net Standard open source library so you can see how it is done.

> Video explaining the DI and showing me make and use the DI outside of ASP.Net Core scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrCoBaQH_aI
>
> Source code: https://github.com/angelsix/dna-framework

This should answer your question regarding how to access the DbContext if you do not understand it already from the video above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrmtZeJyLgg

## Scoped/Transcient vs Singleton

What you have to remember when it comes to whether or not to use a singleton instance is singletons are always in-memory, so you should always consider and try to make things scoped or transcient to save memory, if the creation of that service is not intense or slow. So it is basically a trade off between RAM usage vs speed on some generate grounds.

If you then have specific types of service the decision becomes a different one. For example for DbContext objects you can think of them like a "live, in-memory database query/proxy" and so just like SQL queries you want to create them, execute them and be done with them. That is why they are made scoped, so that when a controller is created (per request) a new DbContext is created, injected, used by an action and then destroyed.

I guess the simple answer is it doesn't usually matter too much and most applications won't have any major concern or issues but you do have to remember singletons stay in-memory for the lifecycle of your application or the app domain if you are in a rare multi-domain setup.

## Notification Count

So the main question is really about badges. There are many things involved in this process and setup, and so I will limit my answer to the presumption that you are talking about a client logged into a website and you are providing the website UI, and want to show the *badge count* for, and that you are not on about for example some Android/iOS app or desktop application.

In terms of generating the badge count it would be a combination of all unread messages or items in your database for the user. I would do this calculation on request from the user visiting a page (So in an Action and returned to the view via Razer or ViewBag for example) that needs that information, or from requesting it via Ajax if you are using a more responsive/Ajax style site.

That again I presume is not an issue and I state it just for completeness and presumptions.

So the issue you are asking about is basically that every time the page changes or the badge count is re-requested you are concerned about the time in getting that information from the database, correct?

Personally I would not bother trying to "cache" this outside of the database, as it is a fast changing thing and you will likely have more hit trying to keep the cache in-sync than just calling the database.

Instead if you are concerned the query will be intensive to work out the badge count, I would instead every time any addition to the database of an unread/new item, or a marking of an item as read is done, you do a "SetUnreadCount" call that calculates and writes that value as a single integer to the database so your call to get the unread count is a Scalar call to the database and SUPER quick.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer! I was thinking of doing something a long the lines you mentioned where I'd decrement / increment depending on if an item was added or marked read. I guess my only worry was having to send this number to the database each time. But if I am understanding you correctly, this should be quick since its just a number?

Comment: Correct. A scalar `single column single row result` will be super-quick you should not have an issue